# Extending external validation diagnostics to experiments with continuous treatment

Tags: experiment-design, causality, propensity-scores, treatment-effect, weighted-regression

Does the external validation diagnostic methods discussed in [Stuart et al](https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-985X.2010.00673.x). (2011) (i.e., inverse propensity score weighted regressions) also apply to the experimental setting in which the treatment is continuous?

Is whether the treatment continuous or binary even relevant?

Are there examples of papers that apply these diagnostics in a continuous treatment setting?

Comment: According to [Hernan and VanderWeele (2011)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3805254/), it seems that as long as the distribution of the continuous treatment is known, "versions of treatment" shouldn't be an issue for "transportability". However, it is not clear to me what additional assumptions are needed so that diagnostics in Stuart et al. (2011) can be used for the continuous treatment setting.